# Webform no duplicate selections with multiple select lists

Tags: 7, forms, webforms

I have a [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) (7.x-4) with two selection lists, with the same content, like

```
A
B
C
D
```

so I would like to prevent users, who fill out this form, from using the same options in both lists.

i.e., if they check **A** they should get an error when they check **A** on the the second list.

what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by writing custom module. If you want to go for a contributed module, the [Webform Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation) module does that

> This module adds an extra tab to each Webform node, allowing you to specify validation rules for your Webform components. You can create one or more of the predefined validation rules, and select which Webform component(s) should be validated against those. By using the hooks provided by this module, you can also define your own validation rules in your own modules.
>
> The following validation rules are currently included:
>
> - Numeric values (optionally specify min and/or max value)
> - Minimum length
> - Maximum length
> - Minimum number of
>   words
> - Maximum number of words
> - Equal values on
>   multiple fields
> - Unique values on multiple fields
> - Specific value
> - Require at least one of two fields
> - Require at least one of several fields
> - Minimum number of
>   selections required
> - Maximum number of selections allowed
> - Exact number of selections required
> - Plain text (disallow
>   tags)
> - Regular expression
> - Must be empty (anti-spam:
>   Hide with CSS)
> - Words blacklist
> - Must match a
>   username

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried "Webform Validation" module ?
"Unique values on multiple fields" applied on those fields I guess it must work.

Comment: I am a bit new here, still learning the procedures.